# how do get header that i set in response object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My action method returns a view.  It looks like the following.

```
public public ActionResult Init(string additionalParams)
{
     Response.AddHeader("additionalParams", additionalParams);

     return View(model);
}
```

The view has a form.  The form is submitted to another action method

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult InitPost(MyModel model)
{
string additionalParams = Request.Headers.Get("additionalParams");  <--- getting null

}
```

how do i get the additionalParams in the post?  Please help.

Comment: Why don't you just put that data into your model?

Comment: Why don't you use additionalParams as a parameter in your model and then bind it in the view. Even, if you do not need it in the view, you can still bind it to a hidden field and get in the form submit.

Comment: if i put it in the model and the form submitted, i get this error: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: what datatype have you assigned the parameter in your model?

Comment: Its a string type

Comment: It seems you are assigning a Path value in your parameter and it exceeds the MAX_PATH value, can you map the path to a network drive and try the shorter path?

Comment: no, i am not trying to map to a network drive.  Just passing additional parameters like this:  "userID=122323:pracID=2342342:anotherID=234324".  But I guess mvc doesn't like this.

Answer (score 0):

So on the Init(), I was using Route attribute routing, that makes urls look like this http://wwww.example.com/23/22/... Apparently this caused issues with the length of url.  So I switched to using query string, by removing the route attribute routing.  Now with this url, I can pass my additionalParams just fine, http://www.example.com?id=222&otherID=222&additionalParams="whatever"